# How to get real execution time when insert huge data to MySQL

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

```
console.time('timer');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
var moment = require('moment');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();

var add = function() {
    var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

    connection.query({
        sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` SET ?',
    }, {username: uniqid(), created_at: now}, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5000; ++i) {
    add();
}

connection.end();
console.timeEnd('timer');
```

I want to know to long the code take to insert 5000 datas to database, but the timer always show before real insert finished, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since queries run asynchronously, you must wait until all the queries have completed before ending the timer. The simplest way to do this in your example is to probably just decrement a counter until all of them have returned, something like this (untested):

```
console.time('timer');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
var moment = require('moment');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();

var remainingQueries = 5000;

var add = function() {
    var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

    connection.query({
        sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` SET ?',
    }, {username: uniqid(), created_at: now}, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        remainingQueries -= 1;
        if (remainingQueries == 0) {
          connection.end();
          console.timeEnd('timer');
        }
    });
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5000; ++i) {
    add();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not work, timeEnd still come out before insert real finished

Comment: By the way, I make it by promise